# Rails: if validation fail, shows error "I18n::InvalidLocaleData - can not load translations from simple_form.en.yml"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-i18n

I just uninstall simple_form

```
gem uninstall simple_form
```

and remove simple_form in Gemfile/related files like simple_form.en.yml.

Now if my app validation fails, below error occurs:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData - can not load translations from
.../config/locales/simple_form.en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: 
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - .../config/locales/simple_form.en.yml>:
```

I didn't setup any i18n before, is there any simple_form related settings I have to modify as well?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's `spring` caching the locale files. Do `spring stop` to fix the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue. Deleted a locale and was getting a similar error. spring stop then spring start fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I had to use `bundle exec spring stop`